# Python Error: DataFrame' object has no attribute 'presence'

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

I've tried accessing the values of presence but I just keep getting this error: DataFrame' object has no attribute 'presence
Im not exactly sure what im doing wrong.

1.Assign values of presence column to y, note you have to use .values method
2.Drop 'presence' column from data frame,
3.Assign df values to x

**Beginning of code **

````
import pandas as pd

columns =    (['age','sex','chestP','ResBP','SrChol','FBS','RestEC','maxHR','EIAng','  oldPeak','slopePeak','MVess','thal'])

 df = pd.read_csv('heart.dat',names=columns,sep = ' ') 
 df.head()


import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

\\ Assign values of ```presence``` column to y, note you have to use .values method

y = df.presence.values    **This is where the error is**

print(y)

\\ Drop 'presence' column from data frame,
df.??
\\ Assign df values to x
x = ??
\\ View shape of x and y
x.shape, y.shape

\\ Use stratify = y and test_size = 0.2 and random_state = 1
xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest = ??

\\ Create a KNN model using sklearn library, k=3 
knn = ??

\\ Fit the model with the train data
knn.fit(?, ?)

**END**
````

**Heart.dat database**

### Attribute Information:

```
  -- 1. age       
  -- 2. sex       
  -- 3. chest pain type  (4 values)       
  -- 4. resting blood pressure  
  -- 5. serum cholestoral in mg/dl      
  -- 6. fasting blood sugar > 120 mg/dl       
  -- 7. resting electrocardiographic results  (values 0,1,2) 
  -- 8. maximum heart rate achieved  
  -- 9. exercise induced angina    
  -- 10. oldpeak = ST depression induced by exercise relative to rest   
  -- 11. the slope of the peak exercise ST segment     
  -- 12. number of major vessels (0-3) colored by flourosopy        
  -- 13.  thal: 3 = normal; 6 = fixed defect; 7 = reversable defect
```

### Attributes types

Real: 1,4,5,8,10,12
Ordered:11,
Binary: 2,6,9
Nominal:7,3,13

### Variable to be predicted

Absence (1) or presence (2) of heart disease

Cost Matrix

```
 abse  pres
```

absence   0 1
presence  5 0

where the rows represent the true values and the columns the predicted.

No missing values.

270 observations

Answer (score 0):

Noted that your columns has no "presence" included. Is it possible df has indeed no df.presence attribute as a result ? What is the output of your df.head() ?

```
columns =    (['age','sex','chestP','ResBP','SrChol','FBS','RestEC','maxHR','EIAng','  oldPeak','slopePeak','MVess','thal'])
```

Comment: Hello! thank you for your answer, I actually managed to figure it out and I was missing presence in my data

Comment: In that case, a "Reputation" click would be very much appreciated.